# AWS Elasticache service update still in scheduling state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

We are using elasticache redis version 6.0.5.

We did not apply service update elasticache-20230315-001 manually and waited for it to be applied automatically after apply by date(April 14, 2023, 18:29:59)

We also changed clusters maintanance window.

Even after more than 2 weeks, the service update is still in scheduling state

According to AWS page, https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elasticache-self-service-update, AWS will send a email notification which we did not receive.

Does AWS take long time to schedule service updates?